# Matlab error: How to solve it

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

How to write `x=(1-x)*(x-ss)*(a*x+1)/(beta-(1-x)*(x-ss)*(a*x+1)*b)` in matlab in order to get values of `y` for `x=0:0.001:1;`

Attempt: EDITED

```
ss= 0.1; beta=10; a = 7.5; b = 4.1; d = .7;
x=0:0.001:1;
y=((1-x).*(x-ss).*(a*x+1))/(beta-(1-x).*(x-ss).*(a*x+1)*b);
```

> error (Inner matrix dimensions must agree) is there.

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: it should be `(beta-(1-x).*(x-l).*(a*x+1)*b);` for the denominator

Comment: @Anthony Error still persists

Comment: The edited code runs for me o.O. You can try break the long equation: `y1=(1-x);y2=(x-ss);y3=(a*x+1);`....Then Matlab will tell which term is wrong.

Comment: It is probably you are using old Matlab version, so you have to make sure the matrices on both sides of addition and subtraction operator are of the same size. You need change `(1-x).*(x-ss)...` to `(ones(size(x)) - x).*(x-ss*ones(size(x)))...`

Comment: ok.............

Comment: I also run this with no errors, but I think you want to write `./` instead of `/` in `y`, to get the result for each value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ss= 0.1; beta=10; a = 7.5; b = 4.1; d = .7;
x=0:0.001:1;
y=((1-x).*(x-ss).*(a*x+1))./(beta-(1-x).*(x-ss).*(a*x+1)*b);
```

Comment: You should try to add explanation to your answers, not just post code snippets. e.g. *"This is a solution because you needed to use element-wise division `./` in the middle of the equation. [Here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) is a link to Matlab documentation about the difference between array and matrix operations which you should read"*